# What is difference between set and add method in sequelize instance?

Tags: sequelize.js

Docs said :

- Add: Associate one or more target rows with this.
- Set: Set the associated models by passing an array of persisted instances or their primary keys.

Since the docs not provide any example, i found it very confusing. Is add will add foreignkey to associated row and Set will set the forreignkey of this to associated row ?

Answer (score 8):

Let's look at a **1:M** example: **Project has many Tasks**.

With set "*everything that is not in the passed array will be un-associated*". This means that if you set tasks for the second time on the same project, **you will replace the previous tasks.**

Whereas with add, you don't have to worry about old tasks being replaced; both old and new tasks will be added

```
project.setTasks([task1, task2]).then(() => {
  // saved!
})

// remove the association with task1
project.setTasks([task2]).then(associatedTasks => {
  // you will get task2 only
})
```

As a side effect, passing an empty array into set will remove all tasks

```
// remove 'em all
project.setTasks([]).then(associatedTasks => {
  // you will get an empty array
})

// or remove 'em more directly
project.removeTask(task1).then(() => {
  // it's gone
})
```

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#associating-objects

Comment: What if the second time , some tasks that were in the first one isn't there , what happens if you use ```add``` ?

Comment: is set a form of updating new associations?